# how to access Remove EventListener in onStop() while the addValueEventListener in static class

Tags: android, firebase, class

```
public static class PostsOffersBuyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{}
```

i have method in the above static class

```
 public void setLikeButtonStatus(final String postKeyBuy)
        {

            mListenegetlikes = LikesofferbuyRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(postKeyBuy).hasChild(currentUserIdbuyoffer))
                    {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(postKeyBuy).getChildrenCount();
                        likebtnoffer.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setText(Integer.toString(countLikes)+(" اعجاب"));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countLikes = (int) dataSnapshot.child(postKeyBuy).getChildrenCount();
                        likebtnoffer.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
                        DisplayNoOfLikes.setText((Integer.toString(countLikes))+(" اعجاب"));

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


                }
            });
        }
```

how to removeEventListener from onStop() method

```
LikesofferbuyRef.removeEventListener(mListenegetlikes);
```

so When I put that code in OnStop() it cannot access to it becouse its method in static class.
Finally I put these above of main class

```
static ValueEventListener mListenegetlikes;
    static   DatabaseReference LikesofferbuyRef;
```

and maybe that work and stop Listener but I don't know if this clean solution ...??

Comment: Have you tried to make your `PostsOffersBuyViewHolder` class non-static?

Comment: I tried to set my  ValueEventListener mListenegetlikes as static at the top of java class
`    static ValueEventListener mListenegetlikes;
`
`    static   DatabaseReference LikesofferbuyRef,commentsofferbuyRef;
`
and then remove it in @Override onStop method
            `LikesofferbuyRef.removeEventListener(mListenegetlikes);`
It's correct and clean code